# debug a C# code that runs by two separate windows services on two systems

Tags: c#, distributed-system

I am new to programming. How can I debug a C# code that runs by two separate windows services on two systems?

More specifically, I have a program in two systems on different networks connected by a common port. A program is executed by running two services; one on each system. I know where it starts. But, I am unable to debug the code.

Comment: Open  a file and dump debug data into file to help isolate where problem is located.  I also add IF statement into code so I can put break point exactly where problem is located.  Suppose you know the program fails a N = 60.  So I add : if(N == 60) int a = 1;  The put break point at a = 1;

Comment: You can run a second copy of VS and attach to the second process

Answer (score 1):

If the program runs in the dev environment and fails once you move it as separate service in to different machines you can write the exception details into a log file and trace the problem.
In Visual studio you can debug two service by attaching the second process from debug menu.